# HTTP GET request returns status OK but content length is -1

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

I am making a HTTP GET request to an OData service. 
The actual service Url is as follows:

http://localhost-70561:8001/TestService/TestService.svc/Customers

When I make the HTTP GET request to the above service it returns proper response. 
But when I make the request to the Url without the port information

http://localhost-70561/TestService/TestService.svc/Customers

I get back a response that status OK (200) but the content length is -1. Also the content type is text/xml instead of atom/xml.

It is unclear to me as to why I am getting Http 200. Since the port is not specified, i would expect Http 404 (URL not found).

Comment: Probably a webserver as part of the OS install.

Answer (score 0):

The port defaults to 80; something might be running on that port.